# How to print and show log using Fabric or Fire base Crashlytics in Android?

Tags: android, google-fabric

I am using fabric Crashlytics in my project, Crash message is working good. But the problem is that I am not able to print log on my fabric dashboard.

1. Code

   ```
   Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
   Crashlytics.log("value");
   ```
2. List item
   [image]

I am not able to see any log message in the dashboard please help me from this.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs get attached to crash sessions. If you click into a Crashlytics issue and select "View all sessions", the logs will appear in the section above the stacktrace.

Comment: you means i can't print log without the crash?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. The log feature is meant to give additional context around a crash.